# Loading html file from server path in extjs html editor

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have been trying to load the html file into the html editor. Is there any way to load the html file in the html editor?
I've tried the following code but it does not work:

```
loader : {url : 'uploads/temp.html', autoload : true}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Ext.Ajax.request](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request) for the request and the [setValue](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor-method-setValue) method to set the html into the HtmlEditor

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it why this question is marked as answered, as the answer is only a workaround for what's going wrong. As I can see there is a typo in `autoload` what should be `autoLoad`.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor-cfg-loader

Or is `loader` just not working for what you want?

Comment: I have already solved the problem. The answer triggered the solution to the problem, that's why it is marked as answer.

The solution is quite similar to the answer above!